# C++ multiple inheritance problem using FLTK

Tags: c++, oop, fltk

i've a problem drawing basic shape with fltk.

I've made 2 classes'Rectangle' and 'Circle' that show normally. Then i've created a third class that inherit from 'Rectangle' and 'Circle' called 'RectangleAndCircle' :

```cpp
//declaration in BasicShape.h
class Rectangle: public virtual BasicShape, public  virtual Sketchable{
    int w,h;
public:
    Rectangle(Point center, int width=50, int height=50, Fl_Color fillColor=FL_WHITE, Fl_Color frameColor=FL_BLACK);
    void setPoint(Point new_p){center=new_p;}
    virtual void draw() const override;
};

class Circle:public virtual BasicShape, public  virtual Sketchable{
    int r;
public:
    Circle(Point center, int rayon=50, Fl_Color fillColor=FL_WHITE, Fl_Color frameColor=FL_BLACK);
    virtual void draw() const override;
};

class RectangleAndCircle: public virtual Rectangle, public virtual Circle{
public:
    RectangleAndCircle(Point center,int w, int h, int r,
                       Fl_Color CircFillColor, Fl_Color CircFrameColor,
                       Fl_Color RectFillColor, Fl_Color RectFrameColor);
    void draw() const override;
```

When i try to draw a 'RectangleAndCircle' instance, the rectangle and the circle share the same color even if i the rectangle color is set.

Here is the code for the constructor of 'RectangleAndCircle' and the drawing of the shapes :

```cpp
RectangleAndCircle::RectangleAndCircle(Point center, int w, int h, int r, Fl_Color CircFillColor,
                                       Fl_Color CircFrameColor, Fl_Color RectFillColor, Fl_Color RectFrameColor)
                                       :Rectangle(center,w,h,RectFillColor,RectFrameColor)
                                       , Circle(center,r,CircFillColor,CircFrameColor){}


void Rectangle::draw() const {
    fl_begin_polygon();
    fl_draw_box(FL_FLAT_BOX, center.x+w/2, center.y+h/2, w, h, fillColor);
    fl_draw_box(FL_BORDER_FRAME, center.x+w/2, center.y+h/2, w, h, frameColor);
    fl_end_polygon();
}

void Circle::draw() const {
    fl_color(fillColor);
    fl_begin_polygon();
    fl_circle(center.x, center.y, r);
    fl_end_polygon();
}

void RectangleAndCircle::draw() const {
    Rectangle::draw();
    Circle::draw();
}
```

I create a instance of 'RectangleAndCircle' in my MainWindow class, and i draw it.

```
RectangleAndCircle r{Point{50,50},50,50,12,FL_RED,FL_BLACK, FL_WHITE, FL_BLACK};
...
r.draw()
```

Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using virtual inheritance. This means there will be only *one* instance of `BasicShape` in `RectangleAndCircle`. This `BasicShape` will have its `fillColor` set by both the `Rectangle` and `Circle` constructors, whichever being called last overwriting the value.

My advice would be to not inherit here, and instead have two fields of type `Circle` and `Rectangle` in `RectangleAndCricle` and then call draw on those separately in `draw`. Inherit to be reused, not reuse (you presumably wouldn't want to pass a `RectangleAndCricle` as a `Circle` or `Rectangle`)